# Error in basic example in gg_season of feasts package

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to use the example in the gg_season documentation https://feasts.tidyverts.org/reference/gg_season.html

```
library(tsibble)
library(dplyr)
tsibbledata::aus_retail %>%
  filter(
    State == "Victoria",
    Industry == "Cafes, restaurants and catering services"
  ) %>%
  gg_season(Turnover)
```

And I get the following error:

```
Error in ggplot2::scale_x_date()$trans$breaks(limit, n = len) : 
  unused argument (n = len)
```

Am I doing something wrong here? Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the solution after browsing through the github issues for the package. https://github.com/tidyverts/feasts/issues/94

The way to solve the issue is to update the `scales` package to the latest version.